# MS Access required fields within form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013, ms-access-forms

I'm trying to get the following done.
I've a form with 7 fields which I want to be required before adding those to the record. The problem is that I use VBA to make every field empty if you change something in a field above. If I set the field as required in the table I always get an error when I'm running the VBA saying that one off the fields is required. Is there a way around this?

Gr.
Ralf

Comment: So you have a field, that when changed, your VBA code clears out the other required fields?  Why do you do that? I'd say removing that logic should help, but I think we need to see your code to assist better.

Comment: The other fields need to be wiped in order to not make mistakes. If the first field is changed all other ones have to be different they can't be the same.

Comment: What mistakes are you talking about? why can't you validate each field individually as the user enters into it, instead of wiping everything out?  There's things I don't understand with this issue, we need some code snippet of yours to help effectively.

Comment: Also please see this to help provide more information to better assist you https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I understand that my question might be a bit vague without context. I just want to be able to check if all the textboxes aren't empty before adding the record. But they can be empty just not when adding the record is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use the *BeforeInsert* event:

```
Cancel = IsNull(Me!Field1.Value + Me!Field2.Value + … + Me!Field7.Value)

If Cancel = True Then
    MsgBox "Missing field"
End If
```